# How is this matrix solved?

Tags: linear-algebra

for the matrix $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 && 0 \\0 &\cos \frac{\pi}{3} &&\sin\frac{\pi}{3} \\0 & -\sin\frac{\pi}{3}&& \cos\frac{\pi}{3}\end{bmatrix}$$ how it satifies $A^6=I $?

How can we solve it though A is an Idempotent Matrix. please help me

Comment: Note that the third column of $A^2$ is $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and the same happens for $A^n$, $n=3,4,5,\ldots$

Comment: Should the lower left 2x2 box be one step to right?

Comment: You **don't have** $A^6=I$. So what _are_ you asking?

Comment: the lower-right submatrix can be seen as the complex number $e^{i\pi/3}$, and since $(e^{i\pi/3})^6=e^{2i\pi}=1$

Comment: -1 for arbitrarily changing the matrix 7 minutes after posting, invalidating all existing answers and comments.

Comment: @pew if you do -1 i am not bothered

Comment: @mystak The purpose of voting a question "down" is to provide feedback to the author saying "you're doing something wrong."  Changing a question to invalidate prior answers is generally considered bad form, and I would recommend against doing so in the future.

Comment: What does it mean to "solve a matrix"?

Answer (score 4):

### Hint:

It can be proved that $A^n=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{3}\right)&\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{3}\right)\\0&-\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{3}\right)&\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{3}\right)\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 3):

Geometrically, your matrix is a linear transformation corresponding to rotating points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ about the $x$-axis by $\pi/3$ radians. So applying $A$ six times corresponds to a rotation by $2\pi$ radians which means it ends up moving every point to itself, i.e,   $A^6=I$.

Answer (score 2):

Use this isomorphism
$$f \colon \begin{pmatrix}\cos x & \sin x \\ -\sin x & \cos x\end{pmatrix} \to e^{ix},$$

and this: the lower-right submatrix can be seen as the complex number $e^{iπ/3}$, for which $$(e^{i\pi/3})^6=e^{2i\pi}=1.$$

Comment: What is the precise isomorphism? (The notation is somewhat sloppy and you'd need to show that it is a homomorphism, not "only" isomorphism).

Comment: @AlexR: And that is a reason of your downvote ?!

Comment: Because the identification doesn't guarantee $f(A^n) = f(A)^n$, wich you used, thus it is an error and you didn't fix it. If you prove that $f(AB) = f(A)f(B)$, i.e. that $f$ is a homomorphism (or an isomorphism), I will remove it.

Comment: But I didn't mention any identification, I just wrote "Use this 
$\underline{\rm isomorphism}$ ..." without proving that it is actually so. It's not necessary to prove any statement in the post.

Comment: Well, even if so, "can be seen as" is an identification and the system prevents me from removing the -1 as long as you leave the post unchanged. If you are so eager to get it remove, edit in a small remark that there _is_ something to do for that identification and I shall remove it...

Answer (score 0):

Look at the characteristic polynomial of the lower $2\times 2$ matrix:
$$
         (\lambda -\cos\frac{\pi}{3})(\lambda -\cos\frac{\pi}{3})-\sin\frac{\pi}{3}(-\sin\frac{\pi}{3}) \\
         = (\lambda^{2}-2\lambda \cos\frac{\pi}{3}+1) \\
         = \lambda^{2}-\lambda+1
$$
So that lower 2x2 rotation matrix $A$ satisfies $A^{2}=A-I$. Then
$$
      A^{3} = A^{2}-A=(A-I)-A=-I,\\
        A^{6}=(-I)^{2}=I.
$$